# Date format not printed correctly

Tags: c#, json

I was passing certain attributes as a JSON string to client side. However, date is not printed in correct format. It is showing some numbers such as 1644506800.. This is what I did

```
        var query = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et && n.BeginDate == b && n.EndDate == e
                select new { 
                   n.EVENT_TYPE_ID,
               begindate1 = n.BeginDate,
                n.EndDate,
                n.BeginLAT,
                n.BeginLONG,
                n.EndLAT,
                n.EndLONG});


   if (query.Any())
   {
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query.ToList());
   }
```

In jquery,

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
         alert(msg.d);

           var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
           alert("A record of this event already exists in the database.\n" +msg.d+".");


            }
        });
```

So can u tell me how to get dates in correct format?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to deserialize the date before you print it

Comment: I need to do it on the client side. So, do u know any default function that i can use to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScriptSerializer serializes DateTime values in Unix time, so you will have to deserialize that integer value into a date first. You can simply use **new Date()** to do it:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
var deserializedDate = new Date(parseInt(data.BeginDate.substr(6)));
```